# Unable to unzip data return by file_get_contents API

Tags: php, xml

The URL I was trying to get data from has the following info:

```
Remote Address:120.138.69.80:80
Request URL:http://mp3.zing.vn/xml/album-xml/ZGJHTlNFQzFNtLFJTDHZG
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK (from cache)
Request Headers
Provisional headers are shown
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp;q=0.8
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)     Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36
Response Headers
Cache-Control:maxage=1800
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/xml;charset=utf-8
Date:Sun, 07 Dec 2014 09:43:13 GMT
Expires:Sun, 07 Dec 2014 10:13:13 GMT
Pragma:public
Via:1.1 VNG-Cache-123:84 (Lusca)
X-Cache:MISS from VNG-Cache-123
```

So I did this:

```
    $url = 'http://mp3.zing.vn/xml/album-xml/ZGJHTlNFQzFNtLFJTDHZG';
    $options = array('http' => array('user_agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36'));
    $context = stream_context_create($options);
    $contents = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
    echo $contents;
```

The result was a lot of weird characters like:

```
����ogvƯ���.��/`7p\����w�d�b�   M����dD��b/    �X4A�E�@>.�I7h���P�����'��w$��M2LSb.lQ�D����x��<��d�Y����?  ���������kI0����|�g���'w'˳�"8�߻�ӷ��[۲~��{w���O Ǳ�X��:��|
```

I assume the returned data has been gzipped. So I tried using gzdecode API as follows:

```
    echo gzdecode($contents);
```

And I got:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Much appreciated if any PHP expert can help me further with this.

RC2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Content-Encoding` is gzip use a header of `Accept-Encoding: identity` to get the content and use `header('Content-Type: text/xml')` to echo the data because the content your getting is XML

```
<?php

$ch = curl_init('http://mp3.zing.vn/xml/album-xml/ZGJHTlNFQzFNtLFJTDHZG');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

//  use a header of Accept-Encoding: identity
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'identity');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');

header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo $data = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: CodingInsane, thank you however, I still get all zeroes after echoing $data.

Comment: if you want to echo it just use `header('Content-Type: text/xml');` i edited my answer

Comment: CodingInsane I tried solving with file_gets_contents using: $options = array('http' => array('user_agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36',
                'Content-Encoding' => 'gzip')); However I had to gzdecode to get the readable result.